# JavaScript text animation on scrolldown

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, parallax

I have an issue with trying to move text from left to right when I'm scrolling down. Basically I reached my goal but with `mousemove` not scroll. Can anyone help me to fix this code ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", animation);
    function animation(e) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".object").forEach(function (move) {

            var moving_value = move.getAttribute("data-value");
            var x = (e.clientX * moving_value) / 75;

            move.style.transform = "translateX(" + x + "px)";
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wheel` event:

```js
document.addEventListener("wheel", animation);
    function animation(e) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".object").forEach(function (move) {

            var moving_value = move.getAttribute("data-value");
            var x = (e.clientX * moving_value) / 75;

            move.style.transform = "translateX(" + x + "px)";
            move.style.transition = "all .8s ease";
        });
    }
```

```html
<div class="object" data-value="25">move</div>
<div class="object" data-value="55">move</div>
<div class="object" data-value="105">move</div>
<div class="object" data-value="145">move</div>
```